# Homogenous system

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove either this statement is true or false.

If  a  system  of  linear  equations  has  infinitely  many  solutions,  then  its  corresponding  homogeneous  system(i.e. changing all the right hand side constants to 0) also has infinitely many solutions.

I believe that it is going to be true, since if you have a corresponding homogenous system, then you can just set all of you variables be equal and then it will have infinitely many solutions.

However, i'm not too sure about that, because i have not found any theory or example related to this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suppose the field where we are working is $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Let's suppose the system can be written in matrix form as $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}$, if $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ are two solutions, then for every $\;t\in\mathbb{R}\;$ we have $\mathbf{y}=t(\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2)$ is a solution of the homogeneous system $\mathbf{Ay}=\mathbf{0}$.